# Stable thermostat-like algorithm where input changes can be large & sudden

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm, function, math

[Edit: I've found an answer - see below]

I have a 3D game world on an iPhone (limited graphics speed), and I'm already regulating whether I draw each shape on the screen based on it's size and distance from the camera. Something like...

```
if (how_big_it_looks_from_the_camera > constant) then draw
```

What I want to do now is also take into account how many shapes are being drawn, so that in busier areas of the game world I can draw less than I otherwise would.

I tried to do this by dividing how_big_it_looks by the number of shapes that were drawn last frame (well, the square root of this but I'm simplifying - the problem is the same).

```
if (how_big_it_looks / shapes_drawn > constant2) then draw
```

But the check happens at the level of objects which represent many drawn shapes, and if an object containing many shapes is switched on, it increases shapes_drawn lots and switches itself back off the next frame. It flickers on and off.

I tried keeping a kind of weighted average of previous values, by each frame doing something like `shapes_drawn_recently = 0.9 * shapes_drawn_recently + 0.1 * shapes_just_drawn`, but of course it only slows the flickering down because of the nature of the feedback loop.

Is there a good way of solving this?

My project is in Objective-C, but a general algorithm or pseudo-code is good too.

Thanks.

Edit: Please note I'm not asking for general advice on rendering performance. I need an answer to the specific question of how to take the shapes drawn in previous frames into account without getting flickering.

Comment: I suggest you post this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You might like (hehe) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm

Comment: @Howard - Thanks (+1), I still think it's relevant here but have asked on gamedev.stackexchange too, let's see which community is the smartest ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each object remember whether it was drawn or not the previous frame.

It it was, be more lenient with it when deciding whether it should be drawn this frame than you would be if it hadn't been drawn the last frame. So...

```
if (how_big_it_looks * (1.2 if drawn last frame, 1.0 if not) / shapes_drawn > constant2) then draw
```

Voila, no flicker. Can't believe I didn't think of this sooner.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to instead of just caring about how many shapes there are to be drawn; consider the importance of the objects; essentially mapping the number of objects to be drawn to the minimum importance for an object to *be* drawn.

For instance, one could use an inverse logarithm:

```
// pseudocode
minimumImportance(count) = 1 / log(count)
```

This yields, as an example; minimumImportance(100) = 1 / log(100) = 1 / 2 = 0.5; but minimumImportance(1000) gives 0.333.

In this scheme, 0.0 is the most important, and 1.0 the least; but that could be inverted by rephrasing the function slightly:

```
minimumImportance(count) = 1 - 1 / log(count)
```

It could also be sensible to add some fuzz to the function, but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

**Edit:** To elaborate, this means that objects should have importances that are relevant, meaning that in any given situation you might have 1 object of importance 0, 10 of importance 0.10, 100 of importance 0.12, etc.

Additionally, this kind of scheme has an added bonus: If each individual shape *also* has an importance; you can simply multiply the importance of the shape with the importance of the object as a whole to get a weighted importance; allowing dynamic de-detailing in busy situations.

e.g.: Player model has importance 0.5; torso, arms, legs and head having importance 0.0, but eyes having an importance of 0.5; and fingers an importance of 0.7.

If the player is the only thing on the screen, it is drawn in full detail; but if there are 1000 other objects; the fingers and eyes are culled.

Comment: I am considering the importance of the objects rather than the importance of the shapes, but I have to use the shapes count rather than the objects count. Some areas are dominated by objects with large numbers of shapes, some by objects with only 1 shape, so the correction has to be based on the number of shapes, not objects.

Comment: Using a method similar to this; that shouldn't matter. You simply use the count of shapes as the count for consideration.

Comment: I can see how this might be an alternative to what I'm already doing, but I don't understand how it would achieve what I'm trying to do. If the camera moves from a place with not many shapes near it to a place with lots of shapes near it (the amount of objects in the world hasn't changed, just where the camera is relative to them), then I want to draw less so that the framerate doesn't slow to a crawl.

Comment: When you have the minimum importance number; you simply omit the drawing of objects that aren't important enough to warrant drawation.

Comment: @MikeHoward: This requires, of course, that there are 10 times as many objects with importance 0.5 as there are with importance 0.33; and similarly, that there are ten times as many 0.33 as there are 0.25.

Comment: It still won't solve the flickering. Anyway, have found a simple answer. +1 for valiant effort :)

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible solutions for you.

**Stateless solution:** For each frame, you have a "budget" of shapes.  Sort the shapes by importance and select shapes starting with the most important one until you've used up your budget.  Draw those.  Since there is no state kept from the previous frame, this system will not oscillate.

**Stateful solution:** You control the minimum importance, *k*, of the drawn shapes as a continuous variable, adjusting it so that the correct number of shapes is drawn, *m*.  The variable *k* is adjusted based on *n*, the number of shapes drawn last frame, in such a way that small oscillations are eliminated.

```
// If k stayed the same last frame, make it less likely to change this frame
// This is called "hysteresis" and is very common in control systems
if k changed last frame then
    threshold = 0.1
else
    threshold = 0.2
end

if (1-threshold)*m < n < (1+threshold)*m then
    // k is close to correct, don't change it
else
    if n < m then
        if all shapes were drawn last frame then
            // don't change k
        else
            // increase k
        end
    else
        // decrease k
    end
end
```

There are a bunch of parameters to tune here.  What are the thresholds?  How fast does *k* increase or decrease: at a constant rate or proportional to the error?

See how much more complicated it is when you use state (e.g. feedback)?  I suggest trying a stateless version.

Comment: I already answered my own question, your stateful solution is basically what I did, but +1 for the more in-depth explanation for others :)